# How to pass all redis records to view?

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to pass all records from Redis to a view. I think i'm doing something wrong with the redis values be cause i can't push it to array or object.

I've tried to to like so :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
var items = [];
  client.keys('*', function (err, obj) {

    for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {

        client.hgetall(obj[i], function (err, value) {
            if(typeof value === 'object'){
                items.push(value);
            }

        });

    }
    console.log(items); // returns empty array

});

   res.render('searchusers'); // need to pass the object here
});
```

When i console log the Value i get

```
  for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {

        client.hgetall(obj[i], function (err, value) {
            console.log(value);

        });

    }
 ------------ Result--------------

{ first_name: 'john123',
  last_name: 'foofoo',
  email: '323233',
  phone: 'foo' }
```

Value is obviously an object...do i need to do a for loop over it's values? or perhaps there is a more simple way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are having async call going on, try this code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var items = [];
    client.keys('*', function (err, obj) {
        const hGetAll = function(i){
            if(obj[i]){
                client.hgetall(obj[i], function (err, value) {
                    if(typeof value === 'object'){
                        items.push(value);
                    }
                    hGetAll(i+1);
                });
            }else{
                console.log(items);
                // res.json(items); for JSON response
                res.render('searchusers', items);
            }
        }
        hGetAll(0);
});
```

I have not tested it, but it should work. Also you can make it more readable using Promises.

Comment: Thanks - i'm getting an error = _http_outgoing.js:356
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: I did - so how can i pass the data to the view?

Comment: That is already happening, in my code check line no 14, once all records are retrieved you send json response, you can modify that to `res.render(items);`

Comment: This works - res.render('searchusers',{items:items});